# Decorate a Combobox in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, combobox, c#-2.0

I have a combobox that contains two display members that are identical, but the values are different, when we store the data in the database it makes sense to use the same name (in their context), however selecting the "correct" item can be a pain.

My Current solution is wherever we fill the combobox.text to do a check if it contains the name, if it does it it checks the value and assigns an extra string to it (so like [name] -- abc, and [name] -- bcd) so you can differentiate. Additionally when you grab the data (use it in comparisons or other store to DB) I'm doing a check to see if it contains [name] and then if it does, I make a variable to store it off as [name] (without the extra string) and use that. This is a TERRIBLE idea, but works.

I.E.

```
// Used in one function
if (blah.text == ("[name]")
{
   if (blah.value == "x")
   {
      blah.text = [name] + "--abc";
   }
   else
   {
      blah.text = [name] + "--bcd";
   }
}
```

and

```
// Used in many functions (5-10)
String blarg = blah.text;
if (blarg.Contains("[name]"))
{
   blarg = "[name]";
}
--> use blarg from here on out, instead of blah.text
```

A really good example of the above is I you want to list folders, but you have two folders in two different paths with the same name (think c:\kjndafv\abcd, and c:\123254\abcd), you don't want to change the name, but you need to indicate to the user that the folders are different, and you don't want to show the entire path.

I had been thinking of a way to "future proof" it, as well as make it a tad cleaner (instead of having to shove the above in all over the place). I was considering using a Decorator Pattern, but I wasn't sure how to go about doing that with a combobox. I was hoping that whenever you grab selected item, or .text, it'll automatically pull the extra string from it, and possibly when you fill it, I can add a conditional to append the string on the appropriate entries.

2 questions, and one comment

A) Is using a Decorator Pattern a good approach, or do you have a better idea?

B) How would you implement the Decorator Pattern for the combobox, or your better idea?

C) I currently am using C# 2.0 (I believe, it's the VS2005 edition), but we will eventually upgrade to newer, I just don't have any control over that right now.

I really appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a user control that inherits from ComboBox and then overriding the properties you want to provide custom behaviour for.

All the standard behaviour could just delegate to the base class.

Comment: Any chance I could see an example?

Comment: I don't really have time. Here's something that should serve as a reasonable example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996411.aspx